# How do I implemet groups using WinJS.UI.ListView with ListLayout layout

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

How do I implemet groups using WinJS.UI.ListView with ListLayout:

```
        <div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div data-win-bind="innerText: title"></div>
        </div>  
        <div id="headerTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div data-win-bind="innerText: group"></div>
        </div>  
        <div id="menu" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{automaticallyLoadPages:false, groupHeaderTemplate:select('#headerTemplate'), groupDataSource:QuickGuide.itemListGrouped.groups.dataSource, itemDataSource:QuickGuide.itemListGrouped.dataSource, itemTemplate:select('#itemTemplate'), layout:{type:WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}">
        </div>
```

The JS file:

```
function getGroupKey(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.group;
}

function getGroupData(dataItem) {
    return {
        group: dataItem.group
    };
}

var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);
var dataListGrouped = dataList.createGrouped(getGroupKey, getGroupData);

WinJS.Namespace.define("QuickGuide", {
    data: dataArray,
    itemList: dataList,
    itemListGrouped: dataListGrouped
});
```

It works only with GridLayout and not with ListLayout.

Answer (score 2):

I think don't think `ListLayout` support a `groupHeader` as `GridLayout` does. Referring to MSDN docs, [`WinJS.UI.GridLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211751.aspx) has `groupHeader` property, but [`WinJS.UI.ListLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211792.aspx) doesn't. Maybe Microsoft think it doesn't make sense to have a `groupHeader` for `ListLayout` because in all the samples that I have seen, the vertically scrolling `ListLayout` either don't have a "group", or they display the "groupHeader" as the list item instead of real items in the `ListView` (ref: GridLayout application generated by VS11). If you wan't a horizontally scrolling `ListView` with `groupHeader`, then just use css to make it look like "list items" instead of "Grids" (ref: /Build// app in Consumer Preview store)

Comment: I think you're right here, bit annoying though as I wanted to use a listLayout to display a simple list, with a single 'header' to select between different groups.